# How can I use `\renewcommand` to wrap `\colorbox` around `\Verb` by only changing the preamble?

Tags: macros, verbatim, backgrounds, fancyvrb, colorbox

**What works:**

I have TeX files which contain code like:

```
I want \texttt{this text} to have a background color.
```

I want the `\texttt` to have a background color:

```
I want \colorbox{lightgray}{\texttt{this text}} to have a background color.
```

However, I cannot modify the body of the TeX files - only the preamble. So I added:

```
\let\oldtexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\colorbox{lightgray}{\oldtexttt{#1}}}
```

That works perfectly.

---

**What doesn't work:**

Unfortunately, I also have:

```
I want \Verb|this text| to have a background color.
```

Which should really be:

```
I want \colorbox{lightgray}{\Verb|this text|} to have a background color.
```

But I cannot get `\renewcommand` to work the same way as above to add the `\colorbox` around it.

---

**MCVE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\let\oldtexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\colorbox{lightgray}{\oldtexttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

I want \texttt{this text} to have a background color.

I want \Verb|this text| to have a background color.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't overwrite basic macros like `\texttt`, just define your own macro and use this inside your document. Use logical formatting macros (i.e. which name *what* they highlight) and not physical formatting macros (e.g. bold, italic). For example if you write a software documentation and want to highlight all your variable names with a lighgray box and tt font create a macro `\varname` which uses a code like `{\colorbox{lightgray}{\ttfamily #1}}` in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `newverbs` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{newverbs}

\let\oldtexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\colorbox{lightgray}{\oldtexttt{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\Verb}{\collectverb{\colorbox{lightgray}}}

\begin{document}

I want \texttt{this text} to have a background color.

I want \Verb|this text| to have a background color.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work as soon as you pass options, like `\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]` for example. See my follow-up question [How can I wrap `\colorbox` around `\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]` by only changing the preamble?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466727/how-can-i-wrap-colorbox-around-verbcommandchars-by-only-changing) for a solution in that case.